# how to close a modal if you click on overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out why my code doesn't work, I would appreciate if you help me, I need when you click on overlay or close button, overlay will be close.

```
<div class="callback-form promo">
            <form name='promoform' id="promoform">
                <span class="close-btn close">&#10006;</span>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" maxlength="30">
                <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" maxlength="20">   
                <input class="callback-submit" type="submit" value="Отправить"  name="save" id="sendPromo" disabled>
            </form>
        </div>
```

js:

```
$(".callPromo").click(function() {
        $(".callback-form.promo").css("display", "block");
        $(".close").click(function() {
            $(".callback-form.promo").css("display", "none");
        });
        $(".callback-form.promo").on("click", function(e) {
            var clicked = $(e.target);
            var x = $(".callback-form.promo #promoform");
            console.log(clicked);
            if (clicked != x) {
                $(".callback-form.promo").css("display", "none");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Could you put together a working example please? **AND** what issue you have, because *not working* is not very descriptive ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.close` click event and `callback-form.promo` firing in same time. Use `stopPropagation()` for no firing other.

Try below.

```js
$(".callPromo").click(function() {
        $(".callback-form.promo").css("display", "block");
});
$(".close").click(function(e) {
  $(".callback-form.promo").css("display", "none");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$("#promoform input").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
})
$(".callback-form.promo").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var clicked = $(e.target);
  var x = $(".callback-form.promo #promoform");
  console.log(clicked)
  if (clicked != x) {
    $(".callback-form.promo").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="callback-form promo" style="background:red;width:300px;height:300px">
            <form name='promoform' id="promoform">
                <span class="close-btn close">&#10006;</span>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" maxlength="30">
                <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" maxlength="20">   
                <input class="callback-submit" type="submit" value="Отправить"  name="save" id="sendPromo" disabled>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like your HTML you've provided doesn't match what the jQuery is looking for, `.callPromo` but perhaps this is just your activator and you've not included it? Also you have two additional click events nested in your initial click event. This isn't necessary and may be what is causing you the issue. Try putting all three click events in the same scope.